# Передать this внутри стрелочной функции

Tags: jquery

Не могу понять как передать this

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $.func = () => {
    $("[id^='wb_indexText']").children().removeClass('menu-style');
    $(this).addClass('menu-style').children().addClass('menu-style');
    console.log($("[id^='wb_indexText']").index(this) + 1);
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#menu').find("[id^='wb_indexText']").click(() => $.func());
});
```

```css
[id^='wb_indexText'] {
  border-left-color: #A9A9A9;
  border-left-width: 3px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

[id^='wb_indexText']:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #FFA500 !important;
}

[id^='wb_indexText']:hover span {
  color: #FFA500 !important;
}

.menu-style {
  border-color: #FFA500 !important;
  color: #FFA500 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wb_indexLayoutGrid1">
  <div id="indexLayoutGrid1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <div id="menu">
          <div class="nav1">
            <div id="wb_indexText1">
              <span id="wb_uid0">РАЗМЕРЫ И ТИП МОНТАЖА</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="nav2">
            <div id="wb_indexText2">
              <span id="wb_uid1">СЕРИЯ</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="nav3">
            <div id="wb_indexText3">
              <span id="wb_uid2">ТИП КОРОБА</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="nav4">
            <div id="wb_indexText4">
              <span id="wb_uid3">ЦВЕТ</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="nav5">
            <div id="wb_indexText5">
              <span id="wb_uid4">УПРАВЛЕНИЕ</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ничего подобного @Streletz, это не дубликат, прошу отменить ваш минус.

Comment: Используй обычную функцию и `.click($.func)` и this будет какой надо. Отдельный вопрос зачем пихать функцию в $

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function#funktsii-strelki-ne-imeyut-svoego-this

Comment: `Отдельный вопрос зачем пихать функцию в $`
Чтобы не засорять пространство имен.

Comment: `Используй обычную функцию и .click($.func) и this будет какой надо`
Не работает https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/d8xk2r90/

Comment: @spoon100500 там всё ещё стрелка

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо @Alexey Ten

Answer (score 0):

```js
function($) {
  'use strict';
  $.func = function() {
    let that = this,
      $mod = $("[id^='wb_indexText']");
    $mod.children().removeClass('menu-style');
    $(that).addClass('menu-style').children().addClass('menu-style');
    console.log($mod.index(that) + 1);
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#menu').find("[id^='wb_indexText']").click($.func);
});
```

Всё получилось, всем спасибо.